# What is the result for this limit $\lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(\int _0^xe^{t^2}\,dt\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$

Tags: calculus

What is the result for this limit  $\lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(\int _0^xe^{t^2}\,dt\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 6):

The function $e^{t^2}$ grows extremely fast, thus, we expect the main contribution of the integral to be around $e^{x^2}$.

First notice that the term in the limit can be bounded above as follows

$$\left(\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}} \ < \ \left(\int _0^xe^{x^2}\,dt\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

$$= \left(xe^{x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}} = e\cdot x^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

If $L$ is the value of your limit, then

$$L \le \lim_{x\to\infty}{e\cdot x^{\frac{1}{x^2}}} = e.$$

Next, we can get a lower bound for the integral by removing values of $e^{t^2}$ which are small in comparison to $e^{x^2}$.

$$\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt \ = \int_0^{x-1}e^{t^2}\,dt \ + \int_{x-1}^xe^{t^2}\,dt$$

$$> \int_{x-1}^xe^{t^2}\,dt > \int_{x-1}^xe^{(x-1)^2}\,dt = e^{(x-1)^2}.$$

Hence,

$$L \ge \lim_{x\to\infty}{e^{{(x-1)^2} / {x^2}}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}{e\cdot e^{(-\frac{2}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2})}} = e.$$

Finally, we have

$$e \le L \le e$$

implying that the limit has value $e$.